# How can I count coherent values that are less than a specific number?

Tags: python

I need to handle some hourly weather data from CSV files with 8,760 values per column. For example I need to plot a histogram with the longest coherent calms of wind speed, which means less than 3 m/s. 
I have already created a histogram with the wind speed distribution but this one is way harder. So I need some kind of string which count the serial hours less than 3 m/s and count them together and plot in the end.

My idea is to apply a string which ask every value "less than 3?", if yes it needs to create a new calm and continue until the answer is no, then finish the calm and so on. In the end it should have a lot of calms from one hour to approx. 48 hours. The output is a histogram of these calms sorted by frequency.

Comment: You should look into [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/why-anaconda) and specifically [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/)

Comment: Alternatively, [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). But either way you need to put some more effort in yourself before asking a question on SO.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Do you have some code that's not working? If so, can you show it? (We don't normally write programs for you... that would take away all the joy of learning how to program.)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't expect somebody would write the code for me, sorry if it seems like that. I just asked for an idea but I think I almost got it. 
Here is my code so far, it should create a vector for every calm and put it into a dictionary. It works but every key is filled by the same vector and I'm not sure how to fix this? (the vector itself is fine, starts at =<3 and count till =>3)

```
#read column v_wind
saved_column = df.v_wind
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

#collecting vectors in empty dictionary
# array range 100
vector_coll = {}
a = np.array(range(100))

#for loop create vector
#set calm to zero
#i = calm vectors
#b = empty array
calm = 0
i = -1
b = []

for t in range(0, 8760, 1):
    if df.v_wind[t] <= 3:
        if calm == 0:
        b = []
        b = np.append(b, [df.v_wind[t]])
        calm = 1
    else:
        b = np.append(b, [df.v_wind[t]])
else:
    calm = False
    calm = 0
    i = i + 1
    for i in np.array(range(100)):
        vector_coll[str(a[i])] = b

#print(vector_coll.keys())
#print(vector_coll['1'])

for i in vector_coll.keys():
if vector_coll[i] == []:
    print('empty')
else:
    print('full')
```